# How collect thread exit status(using join) when cancelled

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to cancel thread from caller or calle, but both are crashing the program

But if I join I am getting the exit status correct.

how to collect the exit status properly on `pthread_cancel`

man page says below

> After a canceled thread has terminated, a join with that thread using
>          pthread_join(3) obtains PTHREAD_CANCELED as the thread's exit status.
>          (Joining with a thread is the only way to know that cancellation has
>          completed.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg);
int errNum = 3;
int main()
{
    pthread_t t_id;
    void *status;

    // on success pthread_create return zero
    if(pthread_create(&t_id,NULL,thread_func,NULL) != 0){
        printf("thread creation failed\n");
        return 0;   
    }

    printf("thread created with id %u successfully\n",t_id);
    // status will be collecting the pthread_exit value
    // error numberis returned incase of error

//  pthread_cancel(t_id);

    if(pthread_join(t_id,&status) != 0){
        printf("join failed\n");

    }
    printf("thread %u exited with code %d\n", t_id, *(int *)status);
    return 0;
}

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{

    printf("Inside thread_func :%u\n",pthread_self());
    //the arguments of pthread_exit should not be from local space, as it will be collected in caller using join
    //pthread_exit(&errNum);

    // if we return it may cause seg fault as we are trying to print the value from ptr(status)
    //return ;  
    pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Just `status == PTHREAD_CANCELED`. In the code you presented, `*(int *)status` will not work - `status` will not point to a valid `int` variable. And `pthread_cancel(pthread_self());` makes no sense - why would you return `pthread_t` value cast to `void*`? Maybe, is that you are confusing - threads do not have "exit status" as in nonzero/zero exit status, like processes. Pthreads return `void*` pointers. The exit status of pthread is `void*` pointer.

Comment: Don't deref `status` in the `printf`. You want: `printf("thread %u exited with code %ld\n", t_id, (long) status);`

Comment: @KamilCuK, may be I am confused, but man pages say we can collect the return (or exit) status (not the value) of thread using join. How do we collect then , as `pthread_exit` use void pointer I am trying to deref value obtained in `pthread_join`  @craig Estey if I use   `printf("thread %u exited with code %ld\n", t_id, (long) status);` then when I pass value 3 in `pthread_exit` , I will get a different value, can anyone post a simple program which works for std errNum and user specified err values

Comment: My [man pages of thread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) say `pthread_join() copies the exit status of
       the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to
       pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by retval`. "The exit status of thread" = "the value supplied to pthread_exit". The `void*` pointer is the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a thread is cancelled (before it has terminated normally), then when you join it, you will receive `PTHREAD_CANCELED` as the thread's return value / exit status.  That macro expands to the actual `void *` value that is returned, so you can compare the value you receive directly to that to judge whether the thread was cancelled.  It generally is not a *valid* pointer, so you must not try to dereference it.

Example:

```
    void *status;

    // ...

    if (pthread_join(t_id, &status) != 0) {
        // pthread_join failed
    } else if (status == PTHREAD_CANCELED) {
        // successfully joined a thread that was cancelled
        // 'status' MUST NOT be dereferenced
    } else {
        // successfully joined a thread that terminated normally
        // whether 'status' may be dereferenced or how else it may be
        // used depends on the thread
    }
```

It is worth noting that the wording of the Linux manual page is a bit fast and loose.  Threads do not have an "exit status" in the sense that processes do, and the actual POSIX specifications do not use the term in the context of threads.  For example, [the POSIX specifications for `pthread_join()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) say:

> On return from a successful `pthread_join()` call with a non-NULL `value_ptr` argument, the value passed to `pthread_exit()` by the terminating thread shall be made available in the location referenced by `value_ptr`.

That's a bit of a mouthful compared to the Linux wording, but it is chosen to be very precise.

Note also that the choice of type `void *` here is intentional and useful.  It is not merely an obtuse way to package an `int`.  Through such a pointer, a thread can provide access to an object of any type, as may be useful for communicating information about the outcome of its computations.  On the other hand, it is fairly common for threads to eschew that possibility and just return `NULL`.  But if a thread did want to provide an integer code that way, then it would most likely provide an `int`value *cast to* type `void *`, rather than a pointer to an object of type `int` containing the chosen value.  In that case, one would obtain the value by casting back to `int`, not by dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Anyone please provide some feedback on my answer